# PHPUnit assert that string has length

Tags: php, phpunit

Is there a method to assert that a string has a specific length in a PHPUnit `TestCase`
or do I have to test it manually using `strlen`?
`assertCount` does not work because it expects a `iterable`.

```
// This is how I currently do it
$this->assertEquals(10, strlen($str));

// This is how id like to do it
$this->assertLength(10, $str);
```

Comment: No, there's no any special method. Just use your `assertEquals`.

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no such option, although I too was looking for one

Answer (score 2):

PHPUnit doesn't have a dedicated function for this, but you can just use:

```
$this->assertEquals($expectedLength, strlen($string));
```